# Smoothing/Averaging 2D Vector Fields

Tags: fitting, interpolation, vector, vector-calculus

I have a list of 2D vectors defined by `{{x,y},{u,v}}` and would like to smooth or average the vectors. For example here are 2 vector fields, the second has noise added to the orientation of each list item:

```
f = Sin[2 x + 2 y];
data = Flatten[Table[{{x, y}, {Cos[f], Sin[f]}}, {x, -1, 1, 0.1}, {y, -1, 1, 0.1}], 1];
noisydata = Flatten[ Table[
    theRand = RandomReal[{-π/6, π/6}];
    {{x, y}, {Cos[f + theRand], Sin[f + theRand]}}
    , {x, -1, 1, 0.1}, {y, -1, 1, 0.1}], 1];
{ListVectorPlot[data], ListVectorPlot[noisydata]}
{ListStreamPlot[data], ListStreamPlot[noisydata]}
```

[image]

Any suggestions about smoothing the field in *Mathematica*? I am trying to interpolate the data (creating an interpolating function using `Interpolation`), but the resulting vector fields are very noisy. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If the vectors are in the form `{{x,y}, {u,v}}` then theoretically the vectors can be anywhere.  In your specific example, they're on a regular lattice though, which would make the problem much simpler.  Is your real data like this too?

Comment: Szabolcs, I am assuming the values are sampled on a rectangular grid/lattice.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are many ways to de-noise data. A simple one is to use one of the built-in filters. For example here I've applied the `MeanFilter` separately to the `x` and `y` dimensions of the data points that make up the arrows (i.e., your `noisydata`). This is sensible because your points lie on a regular grid.

```
args = noisydata[[All, 1]];
datVals1 = MeanFilter[noisydata[[All, 2, 1]], 3];
datVals2 = MeanFilter[noisydata[[All, 2, 2]], 3];
denoised = Transpose[{args, Transpose[{datVals1, datVals2}]}];
```

Now add the plotting commands `ListVectorPlot[denoised]}` and `ListStreamPlot[denoised]` to get:

[image]

Other choices for filters might include `GaussianFilter`. You will probably want to do such smoothing before applying an interpolating function.

Comment: It should be noted that this exploits the fact that the `{x,y}` points are on a rectangular grid.

Comment: @szabolcs - exactly... I've added this in.

Comment: Very nice.  I'm wondering if applying a mean filter to u and v separately is a valid assumption for circular data though?  Would it be more appropriate to assume constant vector magnitude and only average the orientations (which is modulo 2\[Pi])?  I found an article discussing this (http://april.eecs.umich.edu/pdfs/olson2011orientation.pdf) but have not yet implimented the code.  However, I should note that my initial query was, "How does one smooth a vector field", not "How does one average vector field orientations".  It would be great to clarify if this is generalizable..

Comment: Whether it's "valid" or not depends on what you know about the source of the noise. If the noise is added independently at each point, then smoothing separately with a Gaussian (or more simply with a mean) should be fine. If the noise is correlated or comes about by some more complex mechanism, then you would need to take that into account.

Comment: Using bill s' code snippet, I added normalization to force vector lengths of 1, making the resulting field reflect the average orientations:
normalized = Map[{#[[1]], Normalize[#[[2]]]} &, denoised];