# Interpolate a discrete vector field based on vectors which are not on a grid

Tags: interpolation

I have a discrete set of vectors (in 2D), which I would like to use to construct an interpolating vector field. The vectors, however, are not located on an integer lattice and so the answer given at [Smoothing/Averaging 2D Vector Fields](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24099/smoothing-averaging-2d-vector-fields?rq=1) is not applicable. My discrete set of vectors is, for example, given by:

```
DVF = {{{9.33674, 3.98552}, {-0.180697, 0.0760176}}, {{13.8279, 
   4.6567}, {-0.254736, 0.00981569}}, {{6.17762, 
   6.03613}, {-0.0389333, 0.00940466}}, {{9.73972, 
   5.92416}, {-0.0245953, 0.021502}}, {{7.38518, 
   6.94521}, {-0.0328665, 0.0462327}}, {{12.9122, 
   6.20462}, {-0.276557, -0.0910683}}, {{12.1987, 
   7.05313}, {-0.0318079, 0.000668526}}, {{6.54737, 
   8.5326}, {0.011373, 0.117997}}, {{15.583, 
   6.88009}, {-0.15511, -0.133976}}}
```

Here, DVF[[i]] corresponds to the i'th vector, so that the first vector has location (x,y) = {9.33674, 3.98552}, and vector components (vx, vy) = {-0.180697, 0.0760176}.

I think that I should somehow use ListInterpolation, but I am not quite sure how to structure it. I know that I can use ListVectorPlot to produce an image of such a function, but I would like to be able to use the function itself.
[image: ListVectorPlot of a discrete vector field]

Answer (score 1):

Data on an irregular grid can only be linearly interpolated in MMA. Toward this aim, we first extract the position and the x/y components (xs and ys) of the corresponding vector:

```
xs = ({#[[1, 1]], #[[1, 2]], #[[2, 1]]}) & /@ DVF;
ys = ({#[[1, 1]], #[[1, 2]], #[[2, 2]]}) & /@ DVF;
```

Now we interpolate the x/y components:

```
fx = Interpolation[xs, InterpolationOrder -> 1]
fy = Interpolation[ys, InterpolationOrder -> 1]
```

Finally we can make a vector plot:

```
VectorPlot[{fx[x, y], fy[x, y]}, {x, 6, 16}, {y, 3.5, 9}]
```

[image]

Comment: It is possible to interpolate with second order by using ' ElementMeshIterpolation'.